# two submit button for a form cloned

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There is a NEWFORM button to create new form when clicked.and each form has two button. this two buttons work as submit.and has two different request to action page. my question : is it possible to use this two button as two submit ?
here is my snippet :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".newform").click(function() {
    $(".MyForm")
    .eq(0)
    .clone()
    .show()
    .insertAfter(".MyForm:last");
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.MyForm button[type=submit]', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault() // To make sure the form is not submitted 
    var $frm = $(this).closest('.MyForm');
    console.log($frm.serialize());
    $.ajax(
        $frm.attr('action'), 
        {
          method: $frm.attr('method'),
          data: $frm.serialize()
        }
    );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="newform">NEWFORM+</span>
<div class="all">
  <form class="MyForm" method="post" action="secondpage.htm">
    <input type="text" placeholder="name" value="Aynaz" name="a1" />
    <select name="Avg">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">add from DB</button>
     <button type="submit">Remove from DB</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: why don't you simply use the two actions by the click event on both buttons, which will call different functions. Each function would do the work of form submission using jquery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this here i have created two functions for each button element and add class to each class to bind jquery click

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
          $(".newform").click(function() {
            $(".MyForm")
            .eq(0)
            .clone()
            .show()
            .insertAfter(".MyForm:last");
          });
         //click handler for add from DB 
          $('body').on('click', '.addfromdb', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault() // To make sure the form is not submitted 
            var $frm = $(this).closest('.MyForm');
            console.log($frm.serialize());
            $.ajax(
                $frm .attr('action'), 
                {
                  method: $frm.attr('method'),
                  data: $frm.serialize()
                }
            );
          });
         //click handler for remove from DB 
         $('body').on('click', '.removefromdb', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault() // To make sure the form is not submitted 
            var $frm = $(this).closest('.MyForm');
            console.log($frm.serialize());
            $.ajax(
                $frm .attr('action'), 
                {
                  method: $frm.attr('method'),
                  data: $frm.serialize()
                }
            );
          });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <span class="newform">NEWFORM+</span>
        <div class="all">
          <form class="MyForm" method="post" action="secondpage.htm">
            <input type="text" placeholder="name" value="Aynaz" name="a1" />
            <select name="Avg">
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
            </select>
            <button type="submit" class="addfromdb">add from DB</button>
             <button type="submit" class="removefromdb">Remove from DB</button>
          </form>
        </div>
```

**Updated**

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
          $(".newform").click(function() {
            $(".MyForm")
            .eq(0)
            .clone()
            .show()
            .insertAfter(".MyForm:last");
          });
         //click handler for add from DB 
          $('body').on('click', '.addfromdb', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault() // To make sure the form is not submitted 
            var $frm = $(this).closest('.MyForm');
            console.log($frm.serialize());
            $.ajax(
                $(this).attr('formaction'), 
                {
                  method: $frm.attr('method'),
                  data: $frm.serialize()
                }
            );
          });
         //click handler for remove from DB 
         $('body').on('click', '.removefromdb', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault() // To make sure the form is not submitted 
            var $frm = $(this).closest('.MyForm');
            console.log($frm.serialize());
            $.ajax(
                $(this).attr('formaction'), 
                {
                  method: $frm.attr('method'),
                  data: $frm.serialize()
                }
            );
          });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <span class="newform">NEWFORM+</span>
        <div class="all">
          <form class="MyForm" method="post">
            <input type="text" placeholder="name" value="Aynaz" name="a1" />
            <select name="Avg">
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
            </select>
            <button type="submit" formaction="first.htm"class="addfromdb">add from DB</button>
             <button type="submit" formaction="secondpage.htm" class="removefromdb">Remove from DB</button>
          </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! i want to send my form in two different action page. how can i do that?

Comment: Please find my updated answer as you can simply remove "action" from form element and apply on each buttons and find updated javascript function where you can get current button's action and submit it.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @inaz It's completely my pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

No. Both buttons will add the field value into your database. You should specify each button with an id/ class and then bind the appropriate functions to it.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this way.

```
<form class="MyForm" method="post" action="secondpage.htm">
        <input type="text" placeholder="name" value="Aynaz" name="a1" />
        <select name="Avg">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
        </select>
        <button type="submit" class="addfromdb">add from DB</button>
         <button type="submit" ng-click="AnotherButton()">AnotherButton</button>
</form>
```